# Why iterate SelectionKey with iterator.remove() in Java NIO Selector

Tags: java, hbase, nio

Following code cut from HBase RpcServer.java. I can't understand that remove SelectionKey in each time of loop.Are there some reasons in here?Is it a optimizing?

```
      try {
      selector.select();

      Iterator<SelectionKey> it = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();

      while (it.hasNext()) {
        SelectionKey key = it.next();
        it.remove();
        if (key.isValid()) {
          if (key.isReadable()) {
            doRead(key);
          }
        }
      }

    } catch (IOException e) {
      LOG.warn("Run into IOExpection in " + name, e);
    }
```

Comment: I don't know hbase but since there is `selector.select();` at the top I'd guess it's meant to somewhat reset the selection, i.e. remove elements that are being processed.

Comment: @Thomas The `selector` is part of the Java NIO API, and has nothing to do with HBase itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of `selectedKeys` contains the keys to channels that are currently available for their selected operations (eg `READ`, `WRITE`). If you don't remove the key, it will remain in the set, and a next call to `select()` (and family) will still include it, even though the associated channel is not ready for the selected operation.

From the documentation of [`Selector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html):

> A selectable channel's registration with a selector is represented by a `SelectionKey` object. A selector maintains three sets of selection keys:
>
> - The *key set* contains the keys representing the current channel registrations of this selector. This set is returned by the keys method.
> - The *selected-key set* is the set of keys such that each key's channel was detected to be ready for at least one of the operations identified in the key's interest set during a prior selection operation. This set is returned by the [`selectedKeys`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html#selectedKeys--) method. The selected-key set is always a subset of the key set.
>
> [..]
>
> Keys are **added** to the selected-key set by selection operations. A key **may be removed** directly from the selected-key set by invoking the set's remove method or by invoking the remove method of an iterator obtained from the set. Keys are **never removed** from the selected-key set **in any other way; they are not, in particular, removed as a side effect of selection operations**. Keys may not be added directly to the selected-key set.

*(emphasis mine)*